# Get BIOS complete detail from proc filesystem

Tags: bios, linux

Does anyone know how can i get the detailed description about bios settings using proc filesystem. I know commands like `dmidecode` can provide information about bios but they provide very limited information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hwinfo` package can provide a great level of detail regarding your BIOS. I just compared its output with the one `dmidecode` provides with:

```
# diff -ub <(dmidecode --type bios) <(hwinfo --bios)| less
```

Check `hwinfo(8)` manpage for more options.

Answer (score 1):

dmidecode is a wrapper for biosdecode, what can't you find with dmidecode?

you can read some more hardware information from proc by installing `hwinfo` or `lshw`